# SwiftUI CoreData Picker issue

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, picker

I have a project where my `user` Entity can have multiple `directory` Entities (`directories` relationship). I am attempting to create a Picker on one of my views where it shows the `directories` associated with the current `user`. I have tried it in several ways but each time I get the minor bugs to go away I get a new error I can't get past: `Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project`.

I've looked online and it seems this issue can be solved by making the list identifiable (my `directory` entity is already because of CoreData) or by pointing out the id (tried that `id:\.self`). Wanted to see if anyone else knows how to solve it.

What I've tried so far:

```
Picker("Directories", selection: $selectedDirectory) {
    ForEach(user.directories, id:\.self) {
        Text($0.name).tag($0.id)
        }
}.padding()
```

OR

```
Picker("", selection: $selectedDirectory) {
    ForEach(user.directories, id: \.self) {
        Text($0.name)
    }
}
```

OR

```
Picker(selection: $selectedDirectory,
   label: Text("Picker"),
   content: {
        ForEach(user.directories, id: \.self) { 
            Text($0)
        }
   })
.padding()
.pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
```

OR

```
Picker("Directories", selection: $selectedDirectory) {
   ForEach(user.directories, id: \.self) { currDirectory in
      Text(currDirectory.name!)
   }
}
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. That error is usually cause by a typo. Try something like this `ForEach((user.directories.allObjects as? [YourClassName]) ?? [], id: \.self) { currDirectory in`

Comment: @loremipsum Wasn't sure how to make a smaller example. That solved it though. Just can't get the picker to close on click but it builds, runs, and shows the directories. Thank you so much. I'll delete this question in a couple hours unless you want to put yours down as an answer.

Comment: I’m glad it worked. I submitted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
ForEach((user.directories.allObjects as? [YourClassName]) ?? [], id: \.self) { currDirectory in
```